# Can I make a USB drive identify as a printer?

Tags: printer

There are USB drives that can identify as keyboards and even enter commands when connected. Is there a way to configure a USB drive that will identify itself to Windows as a specific printer?

My use case:

I do a lot of testing with printers, sometimes I just need to connect a printer for a few minutes so that certain options and UI become visible in a software program. Currently this requires me to physically move the printer or my PC within USB connection of the printer. It would be great if I could turn my USB stick into different printers.

Comment: How about a virtual printer instead, such as CutePDF writer? https://www.cutepdf.com/Products/CutePDF/writer.asp

Answer (score 1):

In theory you can use a MCU dev board with USB port to achieve what you want. To emulate specific printer requires to flash the specific firmware or at least reimplement the communication interface with its specs. However most if not all commercial printers are closed source. So in practical, it is not possible unless you spend lots of resource on reverse engineering, for example soending years with usb protocol analyzer, which is way more expensive than just purchase all available models of printers.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting idea but ...

you'll have to flash the firmware of the USB device you want to change. And you'll have to know what to change it into. If this is even possible for the device you are talking about (usually companies will try to prevent this, [since it can be used for exploits](https://web.archive.org/web/20190125132040/https://nakedsecurity.sophos.com/2014/08/02/badusb-what-if-you-could-never-trust-a-usb-device-again/)) it will be very specific, there is no general how-to.

Have you thought about using USB over Ethernet (or s.th. similar) as an alternative approach?

There also might be USB development kits provide you with an open interface to change the device ID, however, this will most likely not be the right site to ask this question. I would look for developer forums etc. Maybe there are kits specifically made for the ID being changed.

You could also use a virtual USB port/device (a piece of software that essentially "pretends" to be an USB device - speaking in simple terms), I'm sure there are ways to emulate USB devices out there.

Comment: So practically “No…” but technically “Yes…”

Comment: @Giacomo1968 more or less, yes. I would try to use a different approach then to try a reconfiguration that manufacturers try to prevent.

Answer (score 0):

For [$US30 and up](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07848ZBXT), there are small thermal printers. While not as quite as portable as a USB flash drive, you could actually check the output of the device under test.

BTW, [thermal papers contain BPA](https://saferchemicals.org/2018/01/17/new-report-9-out-of-10-receipts-contain-toxic-bpa-or-bps/) and similar chemicals, so avoid excessive handling.

Comment: Don't think this will work, he wants emulate specific printers?!